# What's the right way to float right or left using the material-ui appbar with material-ui-next?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, next.js, react-flexbox-grid

I can't figure out if I'm using the right approach to get the login/logout buttons to float right in while using material-ui-next ("material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.22",)

It seems they removed `iconElementRight=` from the api. Do we have to use the `<Grid>` now in the appbar? It feels kinds of cludgy. What's the right way to float buttons (e.g. login) in the appbar?

```
<AppBar position="static">
      <Toolbar>
        <Grid container spacing={24}>
          <Grid item xs={11}>
            <Typography type="title" color="inherit">
              Title
            </Typography>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={1}>
            <div>
              <HeartIcon />
              <Button raised color="accent">
                Login
              </Button>
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
```

[image]

Answer (score 91, accepted):

@Kyle You had it right :)

just add to the grid container:

> justify="space-between"

With your example:

```
<AppBar position="static">
  <Toolbar>
    <Grid
      justify="space-between" // Add it here :)
      container 
      spacing={24}
    >
      <Grid item>
        <Typography type="title" color="inherit">
          Title
        </Typography>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item>
        <div>
          <HeartIcon />
          <Button raised color="accent">
            Login
          </Button>
        </div>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

Comment: justify="space-between" // Add it here :)
 container 
 spacing={24}
these three line helped me, thanks.

Answer (score 66):

You need to add `flex: 1` to your `<Typography />` component so it pushes the `<div />` to the rightmost part of the AppBar:

```
<AppBar position="static">
  <Toolbar>
    <Typography type="title" color="inherit" style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      Title
    </Typography>
    <div>
      <HeartIcon />
      <Button raised color="accent">
        Login
      </Button>
    </div>
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

Comment: this sent me down a flexbox rabbit hole. I still don't quite get how this works but I should be able to figure it out

Comment: I figured out this solution. "Flex: 1" means "flex-grow: 1" which means that the Typography element should receive all the used space, That pushes the icons, etc to the right.

Comment: I'd also add that if one wants to **right-align a `<Typography />` component**, in addition to giving it the `flexGrow: 1` style one should also add `align: "right"` to its props as seen in [the API](https://material-ui.com/api/typography/). [The App Bar demo](https://material-ui.com/demos/app-bar/) currently only demos right-aligned icons, not text.

Comment: Do not forget to add `display:'flex'` in the container

Comment: Yes, although `<ToolBar />` is `flex` itself already, `<AppBar />` too

Comment: This should be the correct solution, it's by far them most simple.

Comment: simple .yet powerful

Answer (score 4):

```
<Toolbar>
  <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
    <Button variant='text' color='inherit'>Button1</Button>
    <Button variant='text' color='inherit'>Button2</Button>
    <Button variant='text' color='inherit'>Button3</Button>
  </Box>
  <Button variant='text' color='inherit'>Button4</Button>
</Toolbar>
```

Now `Button4` will be positioned in the far right!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the property align="right"
as shown here https://mui.com/api/typography/

Comment: Going by the docs you linked, using the `align` property will *"Set the text-align on the component."*. I think this would set the buttons text alignment within the button, which is not what OP was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Fresh variant:

```
<Grid
  container
  direction="row"
  justifyContent="space-between"
  alignItems="center"
>
    <Grid item>Back</Grid>
    <Grid item>Next</Grid>
</Grid>
```